# Derive random key from dictionary JSON?

Tags: python, json

The essence of the question is how to derive a random key/value from a JSON dictionary.

```py
def randkey():
    with open("file.json") as file:
        dict = json.load(file)
       
    for k, v in sorted(dict.items())[-1:]:
        randkeyvalue =   f"Name: {v['Name']}\n" \
                         f"Age: {v['Age']}\n"
```

If I can sort the dictionary in reverse order (`sorted()`) and take the very first value from it `[-1:]`. Can I sort it *randomly* and take the first value and of course it will always be different?

Comment: "sort it randomly" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: err... I'm sure Kevlin Henney would take issue with that statement.

Comment: @quamrana he can tell me himself, if he ever finishes sorting that list... And even though the sorting _process_ is random, the result isn't.

Comment: Thx all) agree, my logic is simple in words) it would be easy to just do randomly() instead of sorted() and the dictionary would be shuffled randomly)

Comment: _"shuffled randomly"_ - then... `random.shuffle`? It seems like you didn't research this at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: lol. That's exactly what he did. And that's how I know about it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: import random

def randitem():
    with open("file.json") as file:
        dict = json.load(file)

    dictlist = list(dict.items())
    random.shuffle(dictlist)  
       
    for k, v in dictlist[-1:]:
        randkeyvalue =   f"Name: {v['Name']}\n" \
                         f"Age: {v['Age']}\n"                 BIG THX BRO, now i can change [-1:] to -2 -3 else to derive more random items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `choice` function from `random`:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

For example:

```py
>>> from random import choice
>>>
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>>
>>> choice(list(d))
'a'
>>> choice(list(d))
'c'
>>> choice(list(d))
'c'
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some code to show exactly how `choice()` would be used to select a random key/value from a `dict`.